# How to writerows without csv index headers?

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, python-2.x, webdriver-manager

I am attempting to write the 2nd value in `text_entries` to a file, but I do not want to include the first value in my .csv -- such as index2, index3, etc.

How can I write new rows without adding index headers to my CSV output?
Code below:

```
import csv
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.example.se/list')

def get_elements_by_xpath1(driver, xpath):
        return [entry.text for entry in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)]

text_entries = [
    ("index2", "//div[@class='apartment-fact' and contains(span, '')][1]"),
    ("index3", "//div[@class='apartment-fact' and contains(span, '')][2]"),
    ("index4", "//div[@class='apartment-fact' and contains(span, '')][3]"),
    ("index5", "//div[@class='apartment-fact' and contains(span, '')][4]")]

with open('output.csv', 'ab') as fd:
    csv_output = csv.writer(fd)
    csv_output.writerow([name for name, xpath in text_entries])
    entries = []
    for name, xpath in text_entries:
        entries.append(get_elements_by_xpath1(driver, xpath))
    csv_output.writerows(zip(*entries))
```

Comment: `csv_output.writerow([name for xpath in text_entries])`? `name` isn't defined.

Comment: Sorry; [name for name, xpath in text_entries] :)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what your expected / actual results are?

Comment: Then please fix with an [edit]

Comment: @Christine The webpage is with login & password and in a language most of you won't understand so I think it'll be difficult.. But when I read your question I think my term is wrong: My problem is that when the output is saved onto the CSV the names (i.e. index1, index2, index3) always come along for each new row meaning I get two rows (one row with index names and another with my xpath's).

I want the output to only write the xpath's for each new added row and I've been trying to work it out for an hour now and can't seem to figure it out :(

Comment: This sounds more like a csv / write-to-file issue than it is a Selenium issue. I would like to assist you, but I'm not well-versed in Python write-to-file conventions.

Comment: @Christine Alright, thank you and sorry for that

Comment: No problem, just trying to categorize your question more efficiently so that the right people can assist you.

Comment: @Christine Deeply appreciated and excuse me if I was being misleading :)

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and add a definition of the  `get_elements_by_xpath1()` function you're using to provide a [mre] for others to use to reproduce the problem (and possibly fix it without having to guess).

Comment: @martineau The definition for `get_elements_by_xpath1(driver, xpath)` is there `return` (which brings text in this case, and in another case brings hrefs). As for the minimu reproducible example I'll add a few more lines of imports and code which are missing and might be helpful. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke, I meant that `driver` isn't defined — but it sounds like you got my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
import csv

def get_elements_by_xpath1(driver, xpath):
    return [entry.text for entry in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)]

text_entries = [
    ("index2", "//div[@class='apartment-fact' and contains(span, '')][1]"),
    ("index3", "//div[@class='apartment-fact' and contains(span, '')][2]"),
    ("index4", "//div[@class='apartment-fact' and contains(span, '')][3]"),
    ("index5", "//div[@class='apartment-fact' and contains(span, '')][4]")]

with open('output.csv', 'a') as fd:
    csv_output = csv.writer(fd)
    for _, xpath in text_entries:
        csv_output.writerow([xpath] + get_elements_by_xpath1(driver, xpath))
```

Comment: W Thanks for the tip but now I get each line of code printed in separate rows (instead of the results from the Xpath). The good news is that it did remove the index header names!

Comment: @Neverend Edited. I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for in each row.

Comment: My bad... I was looking to get values derived from the Xpath's. But I did some tweaking with your code and got it to work like this:

'with open('output.csv', 'a') as fd:
    csv_output = csv.writer(fd)
    entries = []
    for name, xpath in text_entries:
            entries.append(get_elements_by_xpath1(driver, xpath))
    csv_output.writerows(zip(*entries))'

So problem solved! Thank you for that, deeply appreciated!